# The End of Anubis vs Red-Eyes Zombie Necro Dragon

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I play with a Structure Deck: Zombie Horde and my friend is always using [The End of Anubis](https://yugipedia.com/wiki/The_End_of_Anubis) against me. My [Red-Eyes Zombie Necro Dragon](https://yugipedia.com/wiki/Red-Eyes_Zombie_Necro_Dragon) has the following effect:

> Gains 100 ATK/DEF for each Zombie monster on the field and in the GYs. When another Zombie monster is destroyed by battle: You can Special Summon 1 Zombie monster from either GY to your field. You can only use this effect of "Red-Eyes Zombie Necro Dragon" once per turn.

We were wondering if The End of Anubis' effect

> While this card is face-up on the field, all effects of Spell, Trap, and Monster Cards that target a card(s) in the Graveyard or that activate in the Graveyard are negated.

negates the effect of my Red-Eyes Zombie Necro Dragon.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, the effect will not be negated.

The critical phrase in The End of Anubis' effect here is (emphasis mine):

> that **target** a card(s) in the Graveyard

The only cards in the game which are defined by the game rules to inherently target are Equip Spell cards. All other cards/effects are not considered to target another card unless explicitly stated as such.

Red-Eyes Zombie Necro Dragon does not require a target for its effect; the monster is chosen at resolution without being targeted. Therefore, the effect of Necro Dragon will not be negated.

Comment: Indeed, the Red-eyes does not target, as its text does not specify it. Just like you said, only until resolution is that the monster is chosen.

Comment: Just a point about which cards target, if a card says `select` this also means target as it is old wording, also cards printed before the introduction of PSCT may still target, so for old cards you can check the card database for the most recent text and if you are still unsure you can check the rulings for that specific card